# Getting all superclasses in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, superclass

How I can get a list with all **superclasses** of given class in Python?

I know, there is a `__subclasses__()` method in `inspent` module for getting all subclasses, but I don't know any similar method for getting superclasses.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the `__mro__` attribute:

```py
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> class B:
...     pass
...
>>> class C(A, B):
...     pass
...
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

This is a [special attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes) populated at class instantiation time:

> `class.__mro__` This attribute is a tuple of classes that are
> considered when looking for base classes during method resolution.
>
> `class.mro()` This method can be overridden by a metaclass to
> customize the method resolution order for its instances. It is called
> at class instantiation, and its result is stored in `__mro__`.

Comment: Thanks. And what's the difference between this method and `__mro__` field? Is this better if I'll use `__mro__`?

Comment: Thanks. So, it is better to use `__mro__` because it already has a result of `mro()`, which calls at class instantiation. So, I don't need to call `mro()` again.

Comment: @VeLKerr it is unlikely to make much difference!

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 methods which work both for python 2 and 3.

Argument can be an instance or a classe.

```py
import inspect

# Works both for python 2 and 3
def getClassName(anObject):    
    if (inspect.isclass(anObject) == False): anObject = anObject.__class__
    className = anObject.__name__
    return className

# Works both for python 2 and 3
def getSuperClassNames(anObject):
    superClassNames = []
    if (inspect.isclass(anObject) == False): anObject = anObject.__class__
    classes = inspect.getmro(anObject)
    for cl in classes:
        s = str(cl).replace('\'', '').replace('>', '')
        if ("__main__." in s): superClassNames.append(s.split('.', 1)[1])
    clName = str(anObject.__name__)
    if (clName in superClassNames): superClassNames.remove(clName)
    if (len(superClassNames) == 0): superClassNames = None
    return superClassNames
```