# Python introspection: Where does the mro() method live?

Tags: python, oop, method-resolution-order

I am trying to acquire a basic understanding of python introspection and in doing so I found the in that regard useful `mro()` method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31028593).

When I (as an introspection exercise) tried to use said method and the builtin `dir()` function in an attempt to find out where `mro()` might live, I however was unable to succeed. Why?

Here is my approach:

- the `mro()` method obviously is available without any imports (unlike `inspect.getmro()` which is part of the `inspect` module; e.g. `str.mro()` returns `[<class 'str'>, <class 'object'>]`
- Since `str.mro()` returns `[<class 'str'>, <class 'object'>]`, the `mro()` method should live somewhere in `str` and/or `object`.
- Yet neither `dir(str)` nor `dir(object)` appear to contain the mro() method. Also help() and help(str.mro) do not enlighten the puzzled student of introspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look with `dir(type)` you'll find the <strike>magic method</strike> attribute `__mro__`. Quoted from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html):

> class.**__mro__**
>
> This attribute is a tuple of classes that are considered when looking for base classes during method resolution.
>
> class.**mro()**
>
> This method can be overridden by a metaclass to customize the method resolution order for its instances. It is called at class instantiation, and its result is stored in **mro**

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100146/12062404) for more about `type` which is the usual metaclass used in Python. Quoted from there:

> `type` is the usual metaclass in Python. `type` is itself a class, and it is its own type. You won't be able to recreate something like `type` purely in Python, but Python cheats a little. To create your own metaclass in Python you really just want to subclass `type`.

Comment: And also the non-magic method `mro`, which just calls `__mro__`.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much!

More on `type` and metaclasses also here: https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/